# Why I can't select iOS 12.5.X as minimum iOS version on Xcode 13.3.1?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, deployment-target, xcode13.3.1

I was asked by my team to bump the deployment target of our project to iOS 12.5.5, but on Xcode 13.3.1 I wasn't able to find the given version or any between 12.4 and 13.0 (like the image shows), why these versions (12.5.X) are not an available option? Is there any technical explanation of why not?

[image: Xcode deployment info section with a dropdown menu with a list of available iOS versions, the version 12.5.5 is absent]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: may be because 12.5 was mainly security updates...

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve the issue:

- Quite Xcode.app.
- Browse to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`.
- Make a copy of the 12.4 directory called 12.5 in the same directory.
- Start Xcode.app.